# How to use python ray for independent computers (each have its username and password) via internet(distributed computation with ip address)?

Tags: python-3.x, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, ray

I know the basic usage of ray in one head node(the computer that user works on) and many worker nodes(other computers). This can be done by filling a yaml file for the newest ray 0.8.

However, now suppose I have three independent machines and each of which has an independent ip, user name and password. I would like to connect to one of them and use it as the head node, and the other two as the worker nodes. But I cannot find any instrutions on ray documentation for this.

Does anyone know how to make this work on ray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can use Ray on different machines that are already set up with IPs and user names is described here:

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-ray-on-a-cluster.html

So basically you need to run `ray start` on all the nodes, with different parameters whether the node should be the head node or a worker node.

It is also possible to use the Ray autoscaler in this scenario, how to do that is described here: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoscaling.html#quick-start-private-cluster

Let us know if you have more questions!

Comment: Link is broken)

Comment: Philipp, does this mean you can create a cluster where the nodes exist on separate networks. I am looking through the documentation and it appears when initializing a cluster via `ray start`, the address is a local one. This would indicate when subsequent ray start commands on other machines are issued, they need to exist on the same network. It looks like the remote connection option is only to use an existing remote cluster, not add a node/worker to it. Is this correct?